# I want to understand the mechanics as to why method is not getting executed?

Tags: python

Even though I know I have assigned an 4 as an argument against the constructor parameter but I want to understand the mechanics as to why method is not getting executed?

```
class my_practice:
    def __init__(self,hours_put):
        self.hours_put=4
        print(self.hours_put)
    def success(self):
        if self.hours_put<2:
            print("Cant succeed")
        elif self.hours_put>=2 and self.hours_put<4:
            print("Can succeed but put more effort")
        elif self.hours_put>4:
            print("You will succeed")
        
s1=my_practice(5)
s1.success()
```

Output: 4

Comment: You have no `eilf` or `else` branch for `hours_put==4`.

Comment: `elif self.hours_put >= 4`.

Comment: Just `else` as the last block, not `elif`. You really want to catch anything else

Comment: What's the point of passing an argument to `__init__` if it is ignored? `self.hours_put = hours_put`.

Comment: @chepner I believe  OP was trying to debug

Comment: @12944qwerty Doesn't change the fact that it doesn't belong in a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The method is being run. But, the `hours_put` parameter isn't passing any of the conditions.

`if self.hours_put < 2:` - This is False. 4 is not less than 2.

`if self.hours_put >= 2 and self.hours_put < 4` - This is also false. Although it is greater than or equal to 2, 4 is not less than four.

`if self.hours_put > 4:` - This is False. 4 is not greater than 4.

There is no place where `4` or `2` passes these conditions. You will need to change the conditions to make it work.

This is an example of what you could do:

```py
def success(self):
    if self.hours_put < 2:
        print("Cant succeed")
    elif self.hours_put < 4: # If it isn't less than two but less than four
        print("Can succeed but put more effort")
    elif self.hours_put >= 4: # Greater than or equal to 4
        print("You will succeed")
```

Comment: Yup,I had missed out on an equal sign,thanks for pointing out